# Load .ascx from string (SQL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I like to to ask that is there a way to load an ascx control from string? To be more precise: I like to make/store a new .ascx in sql then load it to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use the ParseControl function to do what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28.aspx

Example from MSDN:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Debug="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
<script runat="server">
    // System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.ParserControl;
    // The following example demonstrates the method 'ParseControl' of class TemplateControl.
    // Since TemplateControl is abstract, this sample has been written using 'Page' class which derives from 
    // 'TemplateControl' class.
    // A button object is created by passing a string to contstruct a button using ASP syntax, to the 
    // 'ParseControl' method. This button is added as one of the child controls of the page and displayed.
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      Control c = ParseControl("<asp:button text='Click here!' runat='server' />");
      myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(c);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:placeholder id ="myPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```